# Cannot hide button using setVisibility and Handler

Tags: android, handler, delay, visibility, android-button

I am having a problem I've been working for too long now. I'm trying to show a button, and after a delay, hide it.

```
        birdBubble.setVisibility(vis);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                birdBubble.setText("blalb alba");
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
                birdBubble.setVisibility(invis);
            }
        });
        birdBubble.setVisibility(invis);
```

i am doing all of this in a `AsyncTask` because i need to show a sequence of buttons. What it happens is that at the beginning the button is shown and after 2 seconds, the text is changed, but the button doesn't turn INVISIBLE. Any ideas? If you need more code, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: what is `vis` and `invis`??? Show the code where you have defined it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the visilibility like following

```
            birdBubble.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            birdBubble.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            birdBubble.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: i tried, no luck. Ive put INVIS and GONE in the run() method, also tried putting GONE outside of it. Also, all of this is done in the PostExecute() method from the AsyncTask

Comment: oh, it worked! i used View.VISIBLE, not my variable invis and vis. Thanks! I have one more question. I am using this code in a "if" command, my problem is that all the buttons get hidden all at once (after the delay). I want them to hide one after the other. Any ideas?

Comment: you can create a chain of postdelayed.. when a buton is set invisible then post another delayed runnable for next

Comment: i will make a new question